# Issue with Rails Controller create action accepting JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, backbone.js

I have an app that I am building using Ruby on Rails (specifically rails_api) in order to handle ajax requests from a backbone app.

I have been banging my head against a wall with an issue where the ajax request is sent by the app but is not handled correctly by the server, resulting in a 500 error.

Below is the snippet from my development.log file.

```
Started POST "/api/v1/students.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-21 08:01:09 +1100
Processing by Api::V1::StudentsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"fname"=>"Tommy", "lname"=>"", "dob"=>"", "mobile_phone"=>"", "home_phone"=>"", "work_phone"=>"", "email_address"=>"", "street_address"=>"", "suburb"=>"", "postcode"=>"", "state"=>"", "country"=>"", "licence_number"=>"", "notes"=>"", "school_or_uni"=>"", "preferred_transmission"=>""}
params
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO `students` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2013-10-20 21:01:09', '2013-10-20 21:01:09')
Mysql2::Error: Field 'fname' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `students` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2013-10-20 21:01:09', '2013-10-20 21:01:09')
(0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Field 'fname' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `students` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2013-10-20 21:01:09', '2013-10-20 21:01:09')):
app/controllers/api/v1/students_controller.rb:32:in `create'
config/initializers/quite_assets.rb:7:in `call_with_quiet_assets'


Rendered /Users/jake/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@noyelling-instructors-api/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.5ms)
Rendered /Users/jake/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@noyelling-instructors-api/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.2ms)
Rendered /Users/jake/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@noyelling-instructors-api/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.9ms)
Rendered /Users/jake/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@noyelling-instructors-api/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (26.6ms)
```

I'm just trying to figure out where things are going wrong. Happy to post any other relevant code if anyone thinks that it may help.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The problem must be inside your rails controller method, if it's student controller, you want to create new student from params[:student] that's an empty hash. You can create with params itself (not a good idea at all) or wrap your json with new attribute (student in your case). to get that approach you can override toJSON() method of backbone model

Comment: Hmmm. I don't want to over-ride the toJSON method since that will also affect reads. I'd rather just modify the controller.... but I'm having trouble figuring that out.

Comment: I ended up just enabling wrap_parameters and using that. Pretty handy.